# Error consulta MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, distinct

Buenas estoy intentando hacer una consulta en MySql. El problemas, es que me devuelve los campos 3 veces y no se solucionarlo, esta seria la consulta:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pro.id idproducto, pro.nombre productonombre, pro.descripcion productodescripcion, pro.foto productofoto, 
                                    pro.direccion productodireccion, pro.fecha productofecha, cat.id idcategoria, cat.nombre categorianombre, 
                                    per.id idperfiles, per.nombre perfilnombre, 
                                    per.telefono perfiltelefono, per.correo  perfilcorreo
                                    FROM productos pro, perfiles per, categorias cat                                     
                                    WHERE per.id = pro.id_perfiles 
                                    AND pro.id_categoria = cat.id;
```

Comment: Podrías publicar datos de cada tabla? Y cómo se relacionan entre ellas? También debes tomar en cuenta que el formato que estás usando para el join ya está descontinuado, y se recomienda ya no usarlo.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE `productos` (
 `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id_categoria` int NOT NULL,
 `id_perfiles` int NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `perfiles` (
 `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `nombre` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `apellido` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `fechaNacimiento` DATE NOT NULL,
 `id_usuario` int NOT NULL,
 `foto` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `categorias` (
 `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `nombre` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);` he eliminado algunos datos para poder meter las tres tablas

Comment: Los alter table: `ALTER TABLE `productos` ADD CONSTRAINT `productos_fk0` FOREIGN KEY (`id_categoria`) REFERENCES `categorias`(`id`);

ALTER TABLE `productos` ADD CONSTRAINT `productos_fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_perfiles`) REFERENCES `perfiles`(`id`);

ALTER TABLE `perfiles` ADD CONSTRAINT `perfiles_fk0` FOREIGN KEY (`id_usuario`) REFERENCES `usuarios`(`id`);`

Comment: Faltan datos de ejemplo de cada tabla. Sin ellos, no hay forma de saber si Iván Salgado tiene razón (hay datos repetidos) o es otro el problema. Puedes darle en el botón que dice "Editar", ahí tendrás más espacio para hacer tus anotaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Si usando la clausula DISTINCT no te esta apilando las filas repetidas quiere decir que los datos que te esta devolviendo la consulta son diferentes entre ellos. Mira bien los resultados que te da la consulta, de todas la columnas que estas trayendo algunos campos deben ser diferentes entre si.
Recuerda que la clausula DISTINCT se especifica que las tuplas duplicadas (con los mismos datos) son obviadas en el resultado, es decir, solo te va a devolver una fila de todas las repetidas.